# Icon not clickable - Transparent layer ? CSS?

Tags: css, asp.net

I have a buying and selling website and above the sellers photos I have a LIKE button which used to work fine but since I've added a new background and moved things around with new margins it is now not clickable. I believe there's a solution with CSS but not sure how to do it.

When logged in on this page: https://www.onlinecarbooty.com/go-booting.aspx 
You will see the LIKE icons. You can log in with test12345@aol.com and Password: qwerty

Here's the code I have for the like button..

```
<div style="width:50px; height:50px; display: inline-block; background:url('/files/images/icons/stallIconLike50.png'); cursor: pointer;" onclick="addLike('<%# Eval("orderID")%>')">
    <div style="font-size:12px; color:#000; background:#ffffff; border:1px solid #000; padding:0 3px; float:left; margin: 0px 0 0 38px;" id="<%# Eval("orderID")%>"> <%# Eval("likeCounter")%>
    </div>
</div>
```

JAVA

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function addLike(stallID) {
    $.post('add-like.aspx', { id: stallID }).done(function(data) {
      originalColor = $('#'+stallID).css('background-color');

      $('#'+stallID).css('background', 'yellow').html(data);
      $('#'+stallID).html(data);

      setTimeout(function(){
        $('#'+stallID).css('background', originalColor);
      }, 500);
    });
  }
</script>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You have to put all the relevant code in your question. Nobody should be clicking on your link and searching through your code. SO is no a free debugging service. I don't see anything clickable in the code that you provided in your question, so if you're adding the click events in JavaScript, add that code to your question.

Comment: @RacilHilan Sorry.. I have added the VB code which all works fine which is why I didn't include it. If I put the icon elsewhere then it works. There's obviously more asp code around the Like Div but it's about 20 pages long.

Comment: It does say Onclick in the asp code above, which calls this VB code. I'm still just learning sorry.

Comment: The VB code you posted is irrelevant and you can remove it. We only need the code that renders the LIKE button. The HTML code that posted has no LIKE button.

Comment: @RacilHilan Is it this which I've added now? I understand the Asp.net and VB but not sure on Java as someone wrote this for me. There's also a VB file called addLike.aspx.vb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your current markup,

```
.lasteventimg + div {
   z-index: 1;
   position:relative;
}
```

seems to do the trick.

Additionally, `pointer-events:none` on `.stallNew > div:nth-child(2) > div` in your `layoutNew.css:746` disables `pointer-events` on the middle button, so the `onclick` never fires on those items.

---

It's clearly none of my business but, if you asked me, I'd say your website needs professional services for:

- frontend development,
- design/layout.

Comment: Many thanks for that. I added it to my LayoutNew.CSS file but no change.. Is that where I add it. And yep.. I'm always open to criticism :-)

Comment: @Eggy: perhaps I didn't understand your problem correctly. What the code I've posted does is to make these divs usable (they weren't before): http://imgur.com/a/t2JBl - are we talking about the same thing? I thought those were the "like" buttons which aren't accessible. If not, consider providing details.

Comment: Yeah it's the round thumbs up icon I can't get working.. The ones next to it work. I don't know how to use that Inspect element very well so unsure where to add it. I'm just learning. Sorry. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: If I move the like button elsewhere then it's clickable and works. I think I have that many margins and things going on that something is overlaying it where it is and not allowing it to be clicked.

Comment: @Eggy, on line `:746` of `layoutNew.css` you have `.stallNew > div:nth-child(2) > div {/*...*/  pointer-events:none;}`. You either remove it or override it.

Comment: Someone else helped me with that bit.. I've just removed the pointer-events:none; part and that prevents users being able to click on the slider images (Sellers items). But yes the like button is then clickable. I know it's a mess.. sorry.

Comment: So you want the images to not be clickable?

Comment: The item images can be clicked on which brings up an enlargement and the item description. They need to remain clickable. I thought there would be a way to bring the like button forward or something? Whilst leaving pointer-events:none; in there ?

Comment: No the images need to be clickable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148130/discussion-between-andrei-gheorghiu-and-eggybread).